# How to access renamed google sheets

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

I have a google sheets workbook whose sheets get continuously re-ordered. I am able to read each sheet using `wks = gc.open("DatSheet").sheet1`, but this will always get data from the sheet in first position. How can i use individual sheet names to access them, for example: `wks = gc.open("DatSheet").uniquename`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [worksheet function](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spreadsheet.html#pygsheets.Spreadsheet.worksheet) to get a worksheet based on title, index or id. Or you can just use `worksheet_by_title`.

So in your case

```
gc.open("DatSheet").worksheet_by_title("sheet name")
```